# JQuery: How to use an HTML ascii arrow for a toggle indicator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came [across this great JQuery example](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/simple-slide-panel.html) of using a slidetoggle.

I want to implement it exact as is, except for one thing.

The example uses an image for the Up and Down (white) arrow indicator.

Can't I use the HTML ascii up arrow (↑) and down arrow (↓) instead of using an image.

If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe something like this should work:

```
$(".btn-slide").click(function(){
  $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");

  //Toggle text here (I may have the up/down order inverted)
  $(".btn-slide").toggle(function() {
      $(this).text('Slide ↑');
    }, function() {
      $(this).text('Slide ↓');
  });
  return false;
});
```

Basically the idea is just to toggle the text on the link when it is clicked, the same place the author toggles the up/down slide.

More info on [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) here.

You will also need to remove the white background image from here:

```
.btn-slide  {
background:url("images/white-arrow.gif") no-repeat scroll right -50px
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text value of the anchor element as follows.

```
$(".btn-slide").click(function(){  
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");  
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;  
    $(this).text('YourText ' + ($(this).hasClass('active') ? '↑' : '↓'));
});
```

Removing the arrow image is done by eliminating the CSS `background` property of the `.btn-slide` selector.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i prefer use attribute `.attr()`

```
$(this).attr('value', '↑');
```

When testing using firebug, i use `.val()` or `.html()`, after `<input>` will add extra `</input>`. Its not work for me.

Sorry my bad English.